# Symfony 4 "Expected to find class" error happens randomly

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I have a listener called LoginListener which works, but for some reason randomly i get this error when making a request for a route. If i then refresh it doesn't happen, then will randomly happen again.

> Expected to find class "App\Security\LoginListener" in file
> "/home/nibbrstaging/webuyanyhouse.nibbrstaging.com/api/src/Security/LoginListener.php"
> while importing services from resource "../src/*", but it was not
> found! Check the namespace prefix used with the resource in
> /home/nibbrstaging/webuyanyhouse.nibbrstaging.com/api/config/services.yaml
> (which is loaded in resource
> "/home/nibbrstaging/webuyanyhouse.nibbrstaging.com/api/config/services.yaml").

I've noticed this a few times when i say edit a controller and add a new route, it will then throw this error. If i then come in and delete a bunch of white space in the new controller method it goes away.

It's a strange issue this, has anyone seen this happen before and how to solve it?

It does this in dev mode as well as prod, here is my auto load config:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "src/"
    }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
  },
```

Comment: The message comes from Symfony's autowire functionality which scans a directory for php files and expects to find a class whose name matches the PSR4 standard.  Usually clearing the cache takes care of it.  I think there was also a problem associated with some of PHP's opcode caching at one point.  Which PHP version are you using?  Upgrading to the latest PHP 7.4.x might help if feasible.

Comment: What is the defined namespace of LoginListener?

Comment: @Cerad yeh clearing cache and running composer dump-autoload seems to help it. We are using 7.2 at the moment, not sure if upgrading to 7.4 directly would have adverse effects? It shouldn't do should it?

Comment: @peetya App\Service

Comment: @GlenElkins it mostly looks like you have some synchronization between your local filesystem and code server location. Do you use docker or something else? It could be a reason with docker-sync

Comment: Most probably that's the problem @GlenElkins, it expects the `LoginListener` in `src/Security/LoginListener`. So the namespace should be `App\Security`

Comment: @peetya Sorry i mean it is App\Security